# Date field is not getting null from GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, oracle11g

I have developed ASP.net page with C# and oracle 11g. I am updating database table from GridView. But whenever I try to null the date cell getting this error

"String was not recognized as a valid DateTime."
Scan Date data stored in database(oracle 11g) with date as well as time. (i.e. 05-07-2015 PM 05:21:15)

Please refer below code :-

```
protected void grv_pallet_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{
TextBox txt_reswt = (TextBox)grv_pallet.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txt_reswt");
TextBox txt_rackno = (TextBox)grv_pallet.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txt_rackno");
TextBox txt_whcd = (TextBox)grv_pallet.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txt_whcd");
TextBox txt_dtsts = (TextBox)grv_pallet.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txt_dtsts");
TextBox txt_scandt = (TextBox)grv_pallet.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txt_scandt");


string str1 = "UPDATE WI_PALLET SET RES_WT = :reswt, RACK_NO = :rackno, WH_CD = :whcd, DATA_STS = :datasts, SCAN_DT = :scandt WHERE PALLET_NO = '" + grv_pallet.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Values[0].ToString() + "'";


con.Open();
OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(str1, con);

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("reswt", txt_reswt.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("rackno", txt_rackno.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("whcd", txt_whcd.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("datasts", txt_dtsts.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("scandt", Convert.ToDatetime(txt_scandt.Text));

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
grv_pallet.EditIndex = -1;
con.Close();
string display = "Database Updated Successfully..!!";
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "myalert", "alert('" + display + "');", true);
}
```

Comment: Check for null in textbox then pass that to database.
check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2359324/passing-null-empty-string-to-oracle-stored-procedure-from-asp-net.

Comment: @RojalinSahoo Didn't get it

Comment: if your text value is null then  Convert.ToDatetime() function will not parse that one. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xhz1w05e(v=vs.110).aspx . so you can check for null values then parse that one to send to database.

Comment: @RojalinSahoo Didnt get it can you write a code according to my requirement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have changed my code as per below :-

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(txt_scandt.Text))
    {
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("scandt", DBNull.Value);
    }
    else
    {
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("scandt", Convert.ToDateTime(txt_scandt.Text));
    }
```

Now It's working.

Answer (score 0):

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("scandt", Convert.ToDateTime(txt_scandt.Text));
```

Instead of this line you can use:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("scandt",
string.IsNullOrEmpty(txt_scandt.Text) ? DBNull.Value : Convert.ToDateTime(txt_scandt.Text));
```

**Update**

use of  Nullable Types

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("scandt",
string.IsNullOrEmpty(txt_scandt.Text) ? (DateTime?)DBNull.Value : Convert.ToDateTime(txt_scandt.Text));
```

Comment: getting compilation error  **CS0173: Type of conditional expression cannot be determined because there is no implicit conversion between 'System.DBNull' and 'System.DateTime'**

Comment: use nullable date time with the syntax `DateTime?` for more find https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2cf62fcy.aspx

Comment: Now this error is coming **CS0030: Cannot convert type 'System.DBNull' to 'System.DateTime?'**

Comment: try to pass only null like:
`cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("scandt",
string.IsNullOrEmpty(txt_scandt.Text) ? (DateTime?)null : Convert.ToDatetime(txt_scandt.Text));`

Comment: now this error **CS0117: 'System.Convert' does not contain a definition for 'ToDatetime'**

Comment: it's Convert.ToDateTime() not Convert.ToDatetime(). so change it to `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("scandt", string.IsNullOrEmpty(txt_scandt.Text) ? (DateTime?)null : Convert.ToDateTime(txt_scandt.Text));`

Comment: now getting this error **System.Data.OracleClient.OracleException: ORA-01008: not all variables bound**

Comment: put your break point and check which variable is not getting value.

Comment: Each variables are declared properly and getting the values but when I making null to scan_dt field of database getting above error other wise I can able to modify it. According to me Its a problem with not specifying DBNull.Value for null-values.

Comment: is your column in database allow null?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89763/discussion-between-rojalin-sahoo-and-jay-desai).